# Elasticsearch 5.0 Java client "ParsingException[no [query] registered for [query]]"

Tags: search, elasticsearch, java-client, elasticsearch-template

When executing the template query using the java client API, I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: ParsingException[no [query] registered for [query]] ?.

Please find the template query below:

```
POST /_search/template/lookup_temp
{
    "template":
    {
               "query": {
                   "query_string":
                   {
                        "query": {
                            "city_key":"{{phyCity}}"
                        }
                   }
               }
            }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ElasticSearch 5, the APIs are changed a little. So, for querying in ElasticSearch 5 and below.

```
"query": {
               "query_string":
               {
                    "query": {
                        "city_key":"{{phyCity}}"
                    }
               }
           }
```

For ElasticSearch 5.

```
               "query_string":
               {
                    "query": {
                        "city_key":"{{phyCity}}"
                    }
               }
```

Comment: By running the above query in ES-5 I am getting this error Caused by: RemoteTransportException[[IhhQQOk][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: ParsingException[[size] query malformed, no start_object after query name];
Caused by: ParsingException[[size] query malformed, no start_object after query name].   Can you please suggest on how to fix this ?

Comment: In Elasticsearch 2.3 SearchRequestBuilder has setTemplate method but in elasticsearch 5.0 setTemplate is not available what is the alternate option in elasticsearch 5.0 ?

Comment: Could you please the Json again. I tried using curl for posting a template and getting it. It works fine for me.

Comment: curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_search/template/template1 -d '{
>     "template": {
>         "query_string": {
>             "query": {
>                 "_type": "build"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }'

Comment: But we need to execute this using Java client API with OR operator.